# Angular - Image appears while loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a problem, I got an HTML element that acts like a loding spinner, and I would like it not to be displayed. I would to use the observables to be able to load that element only once the data is fully loaded. So far, in my component, i made it like that :

```
const matchTableList$ = this.matchTablesService.list().pipe(
            map(matchTables => {
                matchTables = matchTables.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLocaleLowerCase() === b.name.toLocaleLowerCase() ? 0 : a.name.toLocaleLowerCase() < b.name.toLocaleLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
                this.matchTables$.next(matchTables);
            }),
            catchError( (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.loadingError$.next(true);
                return EMPTY;
            }),
            finalize(() => {
                this.prettyMessageData = new PrettyMessageContent();
                this.prettyMessageData.title = "hello"
                this.prettyMessageData.message = " ";
              this.prettyMessageData.withMessage(this.prettyMessageData.message);
            })
        );
```

and in my HTML i made :

```
<div *ngIf="!matchTablesLine" class="justify-content-center">
    <pretty-message style="width: 100%;" [data]="prettyMessageData">
    </pretty-message>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
        <button class="btn--primary" (click)="createMatchTable()"><i class="add-circle-line"></i>add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the problem here is that, when there is no data, the pretty message is not displayed, and when there is data, the html div is loaded before i got the data, so it's weird to see a button while the page load. I think it is possible to use observables and operators here, but i really don't know which one to use to make this work. Thanks.

Edit : I solved the problem using a simple resolver, which is really helpful in that kind of cases.

Comment: What is `matchTablesLine`? That variable is not in your code.

Comment: matchTablesLine refers to an object which I declared, with an id, a name and so on. I just didnt put the whole code.
@JohnPeters I will try to use your method.

Comment: @JohnPeters I made it your way, like that :
const matchTableList$ = this.matchTablesService.list().pipe(
            map(matchTables => {
                this.isLoading = true;
                matchTables = matchTables.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLocaleLowerCase() === b.name.toLocaleLowerCase() ? 0 : a.name.toLocaleLowerCase() < b.name.toLocaleLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
                this.matchTables$.next(matchTables);
                this.isLoading = false;
                this.changeDetector.detectChanges;
            }),
but i still got the same behaviour as before.

Comment: I'm sorry @JohnPeters , but it still doesnt works. It doesnt wait for the data to be loaded and the button still appears for a second while the data loads. I followed your links details, sounds good and I tried it, but still, doesnt work, or perhaps i am using it wrong.

Comment: it seems like if object in matchTablesLine is not defined then show pretty-message is it like that?  can you try this *ngIf="prettyMessageData.title"?

Comment: Thanks, but still doesnt work. Actually, what i want to do is to wait until the data has finished to load to display my stuff. So far I've been trying with something like finalize(() => this.isLoading = false) but it still loads that damn button first and then the regular display

Comment: @JohnPeters , really, I appreciate your help. But still, the same behavior remains. I put *ngIf="!showContent" and in the ts file : this.showContent = true;
                this.changeDetector.detectChanges;
just as you explained in your article. But i dunno, that button always loads first before data has finished to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to delay the rendering of the button while the `prettyMessageData` is undefined. You can achieve this by adding a `*ngIf=prettyMessageData` on the button div.

```
 <div *ngIf="prettyMessageData" class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <button class="btn--primary" (click)="createMatchTable()"><i class="add-circle-line"></i>add</button>
 </div>
```